# Sum up all odd numbers between 1 and 2n + 1

Tags: beginner, assembly

> **Assignment:**
>
> Write a program which reads a number n from the console. Then
>   calculates the sum of all odd numbers between 1 and 2n + 1 (incl.).

Assignment also on [GitHub, Exercise 0.0](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/4_basic_assembly/0_branching/2_basic_conditional_branching/ex/2_write_code/write_code.txt).

The functions `read_hex` and `print_eax` as well as the header and tail of the script are provided by the tutor.

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc' 

; ===============================================
section '.text' code readable executable

start:
    call    read_hex

    mov     esi, 1 ; esi becomes the counting variable.

    mov     ebx, 2
    mul     ebx
    add     eax, 2
    mov     edi, eax ; edi becomes the limit.

    mov     eax, esi    
    mov     ebx, 2 ; Will be the divisor.   
    mov     ecx, 0 ; ecx will store the sum.
operationSet:
    mov edx, 0 ; Make sure that the register is empty.
    div ebx

    cmp edx, 0
    JE manageOperationSet ; If 0 then skip next operation.
    add ecx, esi   
manageOperationSet:
    inc esi
    mov eax, esi
    cmp esi, edi
    jne operationSet

    mov eax, ecx
    call print_eax

    push    0
    call    [ExitProcess]    
include 'training.inc'
```

I've tested my program with the numbers from 1 to 6 and get correct results. I think it works correctly, but I'm not sure concerning my register usage.

Moreover: What could be improved? Are there weak points in my code?

Comment: Do I understand your code correctly that you iterate over all the numbers?

Comment: Yep. I calc (enteredNumber * 2 + 2) => Becomes the limit. 2 because it's said: n * 2 + 1 (inclusive). If my counting variable has reached the limit I don't enter the loop again.

Comment: I believe you have a bug in your code. You are summing all numbers between 1 and 2N +1 where it should be all ODD numbers based on the problem statement. You are adding too many numbers. You need to skip all numbers where i%2 == 0. You need to fix the code or it is off topic.

Comment: I disagree with you. Had a look at the official solution for the exercise: https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex/blob/master/4_basic_assembly/0_branching/2_basic_conditional_branching/answers/2_write_code/0_0.asm Tested once more with 1, 2 and 4. My implementation is different from the solution but I get the same results: 4, 9 and 19 (25).

Comment: From my solution : " cmp edx, 0 - JE manageOperationSet  " If edx contains 0, because the number could be divided without a left over, then skip the next statement. Which is the adding to the sum. So the even numbers ARE NOT added to the sum.

Comment: some asm tricks: 1) to zero some register you can use `xor r,r` but it will destroy some flags also, so not to be done after some compare. 2) to non-destructive test whether value is even; you can do `test r,1`. This will mask out everything except the lowest bit: when set (ZF=0 after `test`), the value is odd. When the lowest bit is zero, ZF will be ON after `test`, indicating even value. You could also considered to simply start at `1` and add two every step. Before coding try to simplify the algorithm a bit, that direct formula from David is advanced, but += 2 is sort of basic level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Random thoughts:

- A comment that indicates what/where read_hex returns might be useful.
- `mov ebx, 2; mul ebx` could probably be replaced with `shl eax,1`.
- While `div` *can* be used to check for 'oddness', I believe it is an expensive solution.  How about `bt`?
- In fact, why check for oddness every iteration of the loop?  Check once at the top and count by 2's.
- If you aren't using mul/div, then you don't have to have values in specific registers.  This might help you avoid moving values from one register to another so much.

---

But my biggest piece of advice is to junk this whole approach and start over.

I've tried to calculate some solutions here (let me know if I've got this wrong):

```
n   result
0   1
1   4
2   9
3   16
4   25
```

Do you notice anything interesting about the numbers in the right-hand column?  Here's a hint, but before you hover over it, take a moment to try to puzzle it out yourself.  You'll feel better if you do.

> 1*1 = 1, 2 * 2 = 4, 3 * 3 = 9, 4*4 = 16, 5 * 5 = 25

Or in other words:

> (n+1)<sup>2</sup>

With that in mind, there's a much faster/simpler way to calculate results, especially if n is big.

Comment: @user2023861 Agreed.  I can see how the general idea makes a good beginner's tutorial: Looping, conditions, summing, etc.  But it's also a good sample to show that you need to keep thinking about what you are trying to accomplish and not get too wrapped up in your first approach.  I tried to address both.

Comment: Thanks for the great tipps. :) Haven't known the instructions you mentioned because the haven't been part of my course (yet). Learnt a lot from your answer.